# Active record getting results from two tables with no associaion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

I have two models `Trip` and `Spending`, they have no association but they both have `user_id`.

- columns on `Trip` => `id`, `area`, `user_id`, `distance`
- columns on `Spending` => `id`, `area`, `user_id`, `amount`

Example data in `Trip`:

```
id   area   user_id   distance
1    'CA'     2         10
1    'AK'     3         20
1    'CA'     4         30
1    'AK'     2         10
```

Example data in `Spending`:

```
id   area   user_id   Amount
1    'AK'     2         100
1    'AK'     3         30
1    'CA'     4         60
1    'AK'     2         70
```

I am unable to figure out a way to get the following types of output:

1) `sum` of `amount` and `distance` in an `area`, e.g.:

```
area amount distance
AK    200     30
CA     60     40
```

2) `sum` of `amount` and `distance` of a `user` by `area`, e.g. for `user_id = 2`:

```
area amount distance
AK    170     10
CA     0      10
```

I can get records from `Trip` and `Spending` separately and manipulate in ruby, but that doesn't look very clean to me. I have tried using `joins` but records are duplicating.

Any help in constructing an `ActiveRecord` query will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

NOTE:
I have simplified the model and excluded other columns and relations for this question. so I don't have the option of creating another model for area in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is denormalized, can you do something like this?  It might be easier to work with this way.

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :spending
  has_many :trip 
end

class Spending < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :area
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :area
end
```

Comment: actually i have simplified the model and excluded other columns and relations for this question. both the models belong to a user and i tried some like `user.joins(:trips, :spendings)` but it returns incorrect values

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dps's answer but I like to add more in that. Here is the code I tried :

**Model definition :**

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :spendings  
  has_many :trips
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
end

class Spending < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Sample data**

```
a1 = Area.create(name: "CA")
a2 = Area.create(name: "AK")

u1 = User.first

Spending.create(area_id: a1.id, amount: 100, user_id: u1.id)
Spending.create(area_id: a1.id, amount: 300, user_id: 2)

Spending.create(area_id: a2.id, amount: 200, user_id: u1.id)
Spending.create(area_id: a2.id, amount: 500, user_id: 2)


Trip.create(area_id: a1.id, distance: 10, user_id: u1.id)
Trip.create(area_id: a1.id, distance: 90, user_id: 2)

Trip.create(area_id: a2.id, distance: 20, user_id: u1.id)
Trip.create(area_id: a2.id, distance: 70, user_id: 2)
```

**Group By Query :**

```
Area.includes(:trips).includes(:spendings).group_by{|a| [a.name,a.trips.sum(:distance),a.spendings.sum(:amount) ] }
```

If you want separate group by answer then you can try this :

```
Area.includes(:trips).group(:name).sum(:distance)
Area.includes(:spendings).group(:name).sum(:amount)
```

**UPDATE :**
As per requirement, you can replace `Area` model with `User`. Here it will look like :

```
User.includes(:trips).includes(:spendings).group_by{|a| [a.id,a.trips.group(:area_id).sum(:distance),a.spendings.group(:area_id).sum(:amount) ] }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As i said in the previous comment i have simplified the model and excluded other columns and relations for this question. both the models belong to a user and i tried some like user.joins(:trips, :spendings) but it returns incorrect values

Comment: @Aitizazk did you see the chained .includes on the `Group By Query?` in this answer?  I didn't test it but it looks to me like this is type of logic you are looking for. p.s. this is a good answer @Anand Soni

Comment: As i said it is based on the idea that i create a seperate model for `Area` which is not possible in my situation

Comment: @Aitizazk, you need to just replace Area with user. I have updated my answer.